# How to change the color of the selected item in flyout menu?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, flyout, xamarin.forms.shell

I have set a background color and text color and some other color properties like disable and unselected colors, but none seem to change the selected item background color.

Which if the properties below will I have to change to make it look the way I want? Or else what do I need to add on my code?

I have the following:

```xml
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       Title="Example"
       x:Class="TrackBus.AppShell"
       FlyoutHeaderBehavior="CollapseOnScroll"
       FlyoutBackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}">

    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <!--Foreground is the menu icon color-->
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="Magenta" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="Cyan" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />

 <Style Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Cyan"></Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style Class="FlyoutItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Magenta"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Blue"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource SecondaryLight}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

<Style Class="MenuItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="{StaticResource SecondaryLight}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>


<Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="60,Auto">
                <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                       Margin="5"
                       HeightRequest="35" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Title}"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="Title"
                       TextColor="{StaticResource SecondaryLight}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>

    <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="60,Auto">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                       Margin="5"
                       HeightRequest="35" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Text}"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="Title"
                       TextColor="{StaticResource SecondaryLight}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
```

**Primary** is dark blue and
**SecondaryLight** is yellow

Currently I have this:

[image: Inicio is selected]

I want it to look like this:

[image: MainPage selected style]

Comment: Yes, the resources already exists, the blue and yellow color are coming from there. And the menu as it is right it's ok, I just need to mark the selected flyout item with different backgroud color and text color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to override the `FlyoutItemLayoutStyle` ,`MenuItemLayoutStyle`  and modify the value in `CommonStates` and `Selected`  .

```
<Style Class="FlyoutItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Orange" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Orange" />
                        <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Black" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--
Custom Style you can apply to any Flyout Item
-->
<Style Class="MenuItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Orange" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Orange" />
                        <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Black" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to use your snippet, but selected property of MenuItem not works. What  should I check?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to make a custom `FloutItemStyle` template, just as you did inside your ResourceDictionary, like this:

```
<Style x:Key="FloutItemStyle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Orange"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="_label" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Black" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then, with that template, I changed the flyout item appearance similar to what we can find [in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#define-flyoutitem-appearance):

```
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource FloutItemStyle}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                Margin="10"
                HeightRequest="50"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Title}"
                TextColor="{StaticResource LightTextColor}"
                FontSize="Body"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                x:Name="_label">
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

But the most critical part is to assign a name to the Label with the `x:Name="_label"` property to be able to find it with the selected target item (`TargetName="_label"`).

Finally I just added my menu item (Even with some [FontAwesome icons](https://medium.com/@tsjdevapps/use-fontawesome-in-a-xamarin-forms-app-2edf25311db4) in my case):

```
<FlyoutItem Title="MyMenuItem">
    <FlyoutItem.Icon>
        <FontImageSource 
            FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" 
            Size="Large"
            Glyph="{x:Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.User}"
            Color="{StaticResource LightTextColor}">
        </FontImageSource>
    </FlyoutItem.Icon>
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Index}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Hope this answer helps anyone trying to customize every part of their menus, including label colors.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. This works fine for me :)