# Change the selected menu item on shell flyout while navigating via code

Tags: c#, maui, maui-shell

I have a shell flyout menu on my maui app and I use routing on code to navigate as well.

```xml
<!--On AppShell.xaml-->
<ShellContent 
    Title="My Page"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MyPage}" />
```

```cs
//on AppShell.xaml.cs
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MyPage), typeof(MyPage));
```

```cs
//On MyPageViewModel
//Command using CommunityToolKit.MVVM
[RelayCommand]
async Task GoToMyPage()
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(MyPage));
}
```

If I navigate via the menu, the menu behavior is as expected the selected menu item changes to the current page but when I navigate via the code the selected menu remains the previous page.

I would like to keep the navigation stack to allow the user to return to the previous page via the return button but I would also like to **change the selected menu item to the current page**, both to show the **current page highlighted** but also to **allow the user to select that initial page via the menu for navigation**.

For reference on the following explanation lets imagine 3 pages, **InitialPage** **MyPage** **RandomPage**:

Currently if I already navigated via code from **InitialPage** to **MyPage**, and try to select the **InitialPage** on the menu its not responding because it is selected and if I change to **RandomPage** via the menu, and change again to **InitialPage** it brings me to **MyPage** (because I assume is the last on the navigation stack).

I want when I first change to **MyPage** that the selected item on the menu reflects that change of page, and when I change back to **InitialPage** via the menu I want to navigate to the **InitialPage**.

I don't care if the navigation stack is reseted upon returning to the **InitalPage** or if the navigation is added to it such as: { **InitialPage**, **MyPage**, **InitialPage**}.

What should I change, or add, to achieve what I explained above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the color of the selected item in flyout menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747958/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-selected-item-in-flyout-menu)

Comment: no, I dont want to simply "Change color" I want to change the logic behind the flyout navigation. this is not a style question.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this problem. If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that you've found an answer to this problem, but I am going to post this here to help anyone else that may be encountering the same issue. I've just spent the better part of an hour and a half hunting for the solution.

I was encountering the same issue as what is describe in the original question. For me, it turned out to be due to the fact that I was registering all of my routes in **AppShell.xaml.cs** like this:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainView), typeof(MainView));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(SomeView), typeof(SomeView));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(SomeOtherView), typeof(SomeOtherView));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(YetAnotherView), typeof(YetAnotherView));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(OneMoreView), typeof(OneMoreView));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LastView), typeof(LastView));
```

This was fine for pages that were not part of my Flyout menu, but when using `Shell.Current.GoToAsync()` to go to a page that *is* part of my Flyout menu, I was seeing the exact same issue that is described in the original question.

When I was first laying out the Flyout Menu for my app, I had the routes registered like the C# code above, *and* `Route="SomeView"` defined for the `<ShellContent>` that was in my flyout definitions in XAML. For me, I had to remove these route definitions in my `<ShellContent>` mark-up because the compiler was complaining about it by throwing an exception (I'm sorry, but I don't remember the exact exception...but I believe it was complaining about duplicate routes, or something like that). I thought that registering these routes were the same in XAML and the C# code-behind, so I chose to keep the C# and drop the XAML. That was my mistake; they are not the same.

To fix this, remove the C# route registrations in **AppShell.xaml.cs** for your flyout items and add the routes for these flyout items directly in the XAML definitions that you created in your **AppShell.xaml** file. Like this:

```
<!-- We want our FlyoutItem routes defined here, and ONLY here. -->
<FlyoutItem Title="Home">
    <ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainView}"
        Route="MainView" />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="Some View">
    <ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SomeView}"
        Route="SomeView" />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="Some Other View">
    <ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SomeOtherView}"
        Route="SomeOtherView" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Using the mock code-behind from above, our **AppShell.xaml.cs** would now look like this:

```
// We still want to keep our other route registrations
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(YetAnotherView), typeof(YetAnotherView));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(OneMoreView), typeof(OneMoreView));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LastView), typeof(LastView));
```

When I removed the code-behind route registrations and added the `Route` parameter in my XAML file, everything just worked fine. I hope that helps someone!

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting, I don't remember if I did solve it or worked around, I will have a look and try it out later in the week and give some feedback.