# xaml maui - change the color of a selected item in a flyout menu?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, maui, flyout, xamarin.forms.shell

I have the following code block that will display a menu item if tirggered

```
 <Style  TargetType="FlyoutItem" x:Key="HomeFlyout">
        <Setter Property="FlyoutIcon" Value="home_icon.png" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger TargetType="FlyoutItem"
                 Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger TargetType="FlyoutItem"
                 Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                <!-- Code to triger background change -->
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The following code block is used in the following way in a flyout item.

```
    <Application.MainPage>
        <Shell 
 
            <FlyoutItem Title="Home" Style="{StaticResource HomeFlyout}">
                <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:HomePage}" FlyoutItemIsVisible="True" />
            </FlyoutItem>

</Application.MainPage>
   </Shell
```

The current UI looks like the following.

[image]

However, I want it to change if it is selected. For example( with home being the selected tab)

[image]

Things I have tried.

`Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightBlue"`

`BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}"`

How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: Those are not tabs. It is flyout item. Completely different concepts. Read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout Jump to "Appearance". Actually, If you modify the example for "Default template for FlyoutItems" you can more or less get your result.

Comment: @H.A.H. I will make the appropriate change to the title.

Comment: And after that check template in the link I gave you. It uses visual states. Work with them.

Comment: @H.A.H.Is it possible to do the way I already am ? Just as this is a company app I am doing for work and they are very strict on how it needs to be done

Comment: I do not know how to do it with triggers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67767579/6643940 See this answer. It is for xamarin. Uses visual states. The example for MAUI uses visual states too. I do not know what is your company problem with them, and why they tell you to use triggers. If I was you, I would get the job done, and ignore them. But I am not you. So, it seems you have decision to make, I will leave you to it.

Comment: @H.A.H. Yes this works! However I have one issue, is the way it changes the label color still valid ? I cant seem to get it working

Comment: Did you followed the first link I gave you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout#default-template-for-flyoutitems? Show me your current modification, so I can test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MauiWinUIApplication.Resources` to change the flyoutitem for the Windows platform.

Here is the code in the `App.xaml` at the windows folder.

```
 <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
   
        <StaticResource x:Key="NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelected" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush" />
        <StaticResource x:Key="NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush" />
   
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush" Color="red" />
 </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```